# java program Inetaddress

Tags: java

The question I have been asked is too
write java program that reads IP address from input file and writes the corresponding host names in the output file and vice versa.
here is my code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class hw
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{

        FileReader f= new FileReader("w.txt");

        BufferedReader  r = new BufferedReader(f);

        FileWriter  o = new FileWriter("out.txt");
        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(o);


        String line = r.readLine();
        String hn=line;
        String IP;
        InetAddress d=InetAddress.getByName(hn);
        while(line !=null)
        {
        hn=d.getByName(line);
                p.println(hn);
                IP=d.getHostName();
                 p.println(IP);



    }
        r.close();
        p.close();
          }
       catch(FileNotFoundException e )
        {System.out.println("file not found");}
        catch(IOException e)
        {System.out.println("io error "+e.getMessage());}
    }//main
}//class
```

Comment: And what is you question? Does this compile? Does it throw an exception? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your while loop never terminates. Usually I read in a loop like this:

```
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    // process line, i.e.
    InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName(line.trim());
    // etc.
}
```

Also you might consider putting your close statements into the finally block for good form.

Comment: ok thnx actually u helped to solve one of the problems.. but now it's not write the output in the file the output file still empty after run the program I changed while as this:

Comment: while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
      // process line, i.e.
       InetAddress d = InetAddress.getByName(line.trim());

              p.println(d.getByName(line));

        }

Answer (score 0):

kevin corrected your loop error , as for your second question 
I suggest you read [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) tutorial about reading and writing files  Using stream io